# Jquery to limit the range of input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a text box that takes input as amount..I want to prevent the user from entering Amount greater than a certain amount..I tried using ajax ..but its not working the way i want..I think jquery wud do the needful..but I am not so good at it..If any one can help??
Ajax function that i Have written:

```
function maxIssue(max, input, iid) {
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    var strURL = "limit_input.php?max=" + max + "&iid=" + iid;
    if (input > max) {
        alert("Issue Failed.Quantity Present in Stock is " + max);
    }

    if (input < 0) {
        alert("Issue Failed.Enter positive Value");
    }

    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('maxdiv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
    req.send(null);
}
```

Comment: So basically, you're trying to validate the number of orders versus the actual inventory, right?

Comment: Then, care to share us what `limit_input.php`'s return looks like? And why are you passing `max` as an input and not as an output?

Comment: limit_input.php sets the value of text box to max value

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val() > someNumber){
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        alert('You cannot enter that many characters.');
    }
});
```

Comment: OP is looking to limit the value not the length. Remove `.length` and it should be ok.

Comment: I wud be greatful if you help me out

Comment: @Sharvari This code goes inbetween `<script>` tags, or in a javascript document. It also needs to be encased by `$(function(){ // my code });` in order to have the event delegated after DOM has loaded.

Comment: @Alex R. I made the adjustment. I still don't know if that's what OP wants, but either way, should be no problem.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy check my comment in the question. I think he is trying to validate something in the server-side, not just the input length.

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var max=$('#qty').val();
    $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    qty_used: {
      required: true,
      max: max
    }
  }
});
  });
  </script>

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `maxLength` ?

```
<input maxLength="10"/>
```

Comment: I dnt want length.. Actual value shud not exceec

Answer (score 0):

It will helpful for your task.

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10" />

function limitText(field, maxChar){
    $(field).attr('maxlength',maxChar);
}
```

Comment: I dnt want to restrict length... I want the value not to be exceeding a certain limit

Comment: @Sharvari - What do you mean by *not to be exceeding a certain limit*?

Comment: Sorry! I really don't understand what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery validation is pretty simple. You have to define rules and message you want to display for validation, and attach it with your form element.

This tutorial is great help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213138/An-Example-to-Use-jQuery-Validation-Plugin

Here's 101 on validation, in case you want to try it out. I am using cdn, but you can add reference to library in your path.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Validation Test</title>
<!-- Importing jquery and jquery ui library from cdn -->

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<!-- End of Import -->

</head>
<body>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testvalidation").validate({

      rules: {
          title: "required",
          description: {
            required:true,
            maxlength:4000
        }
      },
    messages: {
      title: "Title is Required",
      description: {
          required : "Description is Required",
          maxlength: "Should be less than 4000 Characters"
      }
    }
   });
  });
  </script>

  <style>

    #testvalidation .error{
    color: #FB3A3A;
    font-weight:300;

} 

</style>

  <form action=update.jsp class="form-horizontal" id="testvalidation">

  <input name="title" type="text"></input><br>
  <textarea name="description"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can pass in the object for rules on client side.